# Задать условие в qml

Tags: qt, qml

У меня есть индикатор

```
Image {
    id: indicator1
    x: 320
    y: 257
    width: 10
    height: 10
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    source: "../images/grn.png"
    visible: true
}
```

Мне его надо показывать либо скрывать в зависимости от полученного значения (0 или 1), которое хранится в stringList[0]. Подскажите как организовать можно ?
Я знаю метод, как цвета менять таким способом, но с видимостью не прокатило.

```
visible: stringList[0] === 0 || stringList[0] === 1 ? false: true
```

Comment: ваше условие всегда возвращает false, может проблема в этом?

Comment: т.е. мой вариант реализации правильный, просто условия всегда одинаковые?)
Я думаю нет, в 0 элементе я посылал и 1 и 0 , результат всегда один и тот же... 
И у меня условие всегда возвращает true , и после этого действия у меня в  stringList[0] хранится не число, а true....

Comment: Полагаю, что QML никак не может узнать, что элементы `stringList` изменились, поэтому подобная привязка не будет работать.

Comment: Так оно и не работает, я и прошу по этому, чтоб подсказали, как реализовать ... чтоб работало

Comment: Там где меняете `stringList`, там и обновляйте то, что будет изменять `visible`, будь это свойство или посылка сигнала. Варианты могут быть разные, всё зависит от кода и его организации.

Comment: Все, решил проблему!)))
Все дело в том, что значения которые я получал были типа StringList... 
а сравнивал я их с типом int.... 
visible: stringList[0] === "0" || stringList[0] === "1" ? false: true
Взял числа в кавычки  и все заработало!